# Android Room - emit single item update

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-room

I'm using Android Room to load data.
my query is this:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM TrackedItem where isArchived = 0 ORDER BY creationDate DESC")
Flowable<List<TrackedItem>> getAll();
```

When calling getAll() I get all the items at the first time.
Then, I'm updating all the items using a network request.
What happens is that if I have 100 items, the getAll() will emit 100 times the entire list, which will update the RecyclerView 100 times.

Best practice for getting a single item that was changed and calling notifyItemChanged?

Thanks.

Comment: "I'm updating all the items using a network request" -- how are you doing this? One DAO call? 100 DAO calls? Something else?

Comment: changed it now to One DAO call

Comment: And... did that clear up the problem? I haven't tested this scenario, and so I would hope that a single DAO call would result in a single update through the `Flowable`, but there's a reason Room is in alpha... :-)

Comment: Yep, that seems to solve the issue. Wiil update my answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, if someone gets the same issue.
Instead of saving each item after an update, I save all of them once 
calling @Insert with (TrackedItem... items).
which will only emits one update.